# Delay random position jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that displays 4 divs at a random hight at specified distances from the viewport sides, each div appears with a different delay speed and then moves around the page at random.

I want to add a delay to the movement of each div so they don't all start and stop moving at the same time but every time I add ad .delay() it breaks. Any help?

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="loopbox">
      <div id="rand_pos" class="loop mobile box1">L</div>       
      <div id="rand_pos" class="loop mobile box2">O</div>       
      <div id="rand_pos" class="loop mobile box3">O</div>   
      <div id="rand_pos" class="loop mobile box4">P</div>
   </div>
   <div class="info">
      <h1>COMING SOON</h1>
      <p>info@loopstudio.uk</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

***CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus&display=swap');

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

html { overflow: hidden; }

body {
   margin: 0;
   background-color:#FFF9F3;
}

p,h1 {
   font-family:sans-serif;
}

h1{
   font-weight:100;
}

.loop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
   font-size:22vw;
   font-family:'Marcellus', serif;
   font-weight:100;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.loop:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.5,.01,.01,.05) 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}


.box1{
  top:10vh;
  left:8vw;
     display:none;
}
.box2{
  top:20vh;
   left:30vw;
   display:none;
}
.box3{
  top:30vh;
   right:35vw;
   display:none;
}
.box4{
  top:40vh;
   right:10vw;
   display:none;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  resize: both;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
   height:auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  resize: both;
   text-align:center;
   z-index:-1000;  
}
```

**JS**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('.box1').delay(500).fadeIn(850);
   $('.box2').delay(1000).fadeIn(850);
   $('.box3').delay(750).fadeIn(850);
    $('.box4').delay(1250).fadeIn(850);
});

$('document').ready(function() {
  var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random()*bodyHeight));

  $('#rand_pos').css('top', randPosY);

});



$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv('.box1');
    animateDiv('.box2');
    animateDiv('.box3');
    animateDiv('.box4');
});

function makeNewPosition(){


    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(myclass){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $(myclass).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, 8000, function(){
      animateDiv(myclass);        
    });

};
```

Comment: With all due respect, why don't you try using GreenSock (https://greensock.com/) or other animation tool? Animating with jQuery is similar to use a scooter instead of a mountain bike to go downhill in a trail. You will get to your location but is going to be a bumpy ride ;)

Comment: breaks in what way? I created a snippet with your code and it seemed to work fine

Comment: @Anthony The code above works but I can't get the characters to animate at different time, they all start and stop moving at the same time. I want to offset them a bit to make it seem more 'random'

Comment: Using your code, I made this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk3ej6fx/) and just increased the delay of each letter. Is this not what yours is doing/what you want?